# How to take time as an input in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a script that will take a time as an input, and output times in 90-minute increments backwards. I'm using it to calculate optimal times for me to fall asleep.

For example, if I want to wake up at 12 pm, the program would output

```
10:30 am, 9:00 am, 7:30, am
```

, and so on.

What I have so far is:

```
puts 'what time do you want to wake up?: '
time = gets.chomp
```

What can I do from here?

Comment: What is the logic that puts `,` after `7:30`? What is the input to the output you have, is it `12 pm` or `12:00 pm`, or something else? How long should the list continue?

Comment: Ah. It should continue for no greater than 24 hours.

Comment: You'll have to do a better job of stating the question (with an edit, please, not in comments).  In your example, is 12:00 pm the "input"?  If so, why did you begin at 10:30 am, and what interpretation are you putting on the times in that sequence?  Is 12:00 pm later in the same day (as 10:30 am) or at the end of the previous day?  How is time to be entered ("12:00 pm", "12:00p", "12pm", "24:00", etc.)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Look into how to convert variables (in some ways of saying it, "cast" them) between types.  You have a string input here.  You can see that by entering

```
puts time.class
```

after the `chomp`.

There are many ways to do the conversion.  All of them are methods of the `Time` class.  You can [pick the best one for your needs, here.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html)

Then you can do the date math with something like

```
step_unit = 60 * 90
# ....
n.times do
  print "#{converted_time -= step_unit}, "
end
```

Remember to first convert your time value, and calculate the number of steps to cover in 24 hr.

---

You can learn the core classes that ship with Ruby, [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/)